# Problem with meta favicon

Tags: bug, status-completed

This site (meta.codereview.stackexchange.com) seems to be missing a favicon.  This affects not only browsers but also the inbox of the StackExchange dropdown:

[image]

Comment: You seem to be correct! http://sstatic.net/codereviewmeta/img/favicon.ico

Comment: Looking into it...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I messed up. I have made a new favicon, should be in the next build

Comment: Don't worry, we still think you're awesome!

Comment: @zolomon awww thanks1

Answer (score 2):

Actually the favicon [does exist](http://sstatic.net/codereviewmeta/img/favicon.ico), but it's in the wrong format. Apparently it was saved in Photoshop's format rather than as an icon, so the browsers can't display it.

Comment: +1 But you linked to the code review icon not the code review meta icon :) Url: http://sstatic.net/codereviewmeta/img/favicon.ico

Comment: @edorian: Blargh. Don't know why I did that. Fixed now. Thanks.